# Aurelia code sharing on custom elements and custom attributes

Tags: package, aurelia, reusability, code-sharing

I am developing some custom elements and some custom attributes in aurelia. these custom elements will be then used in more that one project. So I don't want to copy the resource folder from project to project. What is the best way to share these types of codes.

I have searched the web a little and found that I can do this by NPM. But I want to publish them publicly and don't want to pay for private area. But I want a way to do this on my own server (or my own Git server).

So what are the possible solutions and which one is better?

Comment: It's not really an aurelia question, but rather a NPm question.
the way I see it, you can either set up a private NPM repository (check out verdiccio), or just use a simple npm link to a local folder

Comment: So at least some links to provided solutions will be good idea. And some comparison between them, or link to a comparison page.

Comment: you are right, it will be a very good idea indeed. so if you find some - share it with the group.

Comment: :) OK I wil do it soon if I have found any IGW. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I dont thibk you will find comparison between those two method, because they are not two way of accomplishibg the same task. but in your case.. they will both work